# Is there a formula for computing the number of arrangements from a set of N elements groupped in K groups?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Eg: `N=3`, `K=2`

There will be two groups in each solution. We need to calculate the number of such possible solutions. Consider the set `S={1,2,3}`. The possible solutions are:

```
{1} {2,3}
{1} {3,2}
{2} {1,3}
{2} {3,1}
{3} {1,2}
{3} {2,1}
{1,2} {3}
{2,1} {3}
{1,3} {2}
{3,1} {2}
{2,3} {1}
{3,2} {1}
```

The result for this example is: `12`.

Eg: `N=4, K=3`

```
{1} {2} {3,4}
{1} {2} {4,3}
{1} {2,3} {4}
{1} {3,2} {4}
....
```

Can we generalize this formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that the example for $N=3$, $K=2$ is correct, meaning that the internal order of the elements in individual groups matters.

There are $N!$ ways of lining up our $N$ objects. That produces $N-1$ interobject "gaps." We **choose** $K-1$ of them to put a separator into.

That can  be done in $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$ ways, for a total of $N!\binom{N-1}{K-1}$.

**Remark:** If internal order within groups does not matter, the solution is quite different, and uses [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Thanks for the remark - I was actually looking for a formula for both problems (when the order of the groups matters and when it doesn't). What's the meaning of $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$?

Comment: You are welcome. In general, $\binom{n}{k}$ is a *binomial coefficient*, with formula $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, so in our case $\frac{(N-1)!}{(K-1)!(N-K)!}$. You may know $\binom{n}{k}$ under another notation, such as $C(n,k)$ or $C^n_k$. There are many variants, but the standard in mathematics in $\binom{n}{k}$. It is the number of ways to **choose** $k$ objects from a collection of $n$ distinct objects.

Comment: When order in the groups does not matter, things get more complicated. You could look at the Wikipedia article on Stirling numbers of the second kind. It may be a bit tough to read if you are not yet familiar with binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arrangement of a set $S = \{ a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n\}$.

We need to partition this set into $K$ groups such that each group contains more than one element such that the relative order of elements remain same. For example for $S = \{1,2,3\}$, the partition $\{1\},\{2,3\}$ will be valid but $\{2\},\{1,3\}$ will be invalid.

Let $x_i$ be the number of elements in $i^{th}$ partition, so we have $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_k = n$$

where each $x_i \ge 1$. This is a classical problem and we know the number of ways for the above problem is $$P = \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

There are $n!$ sets, S are possible so number of arrangements will be equal to $n!*P$.